# list comprehension within list of tuple

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

my problem is something like this:

```
a=[(0,0,'customer',["Hi, I'm user"]),
 (0,1,'agent',['Hi Welcome']),
 (0,2,'customer',["i would like to know"]),
 (0, 3, 'agent', ['Yes']),
 (0, 3, 'agent', ['Only credit']),
 (0, 4, 'customer', ['oic...']),
 (0, 4, 'customer', ['sub line?']),
 (0, 4, 'customer', ['is it?']),
 (0, 5, 'agent', ['no subline']),
 (0, 6, 'customer', ['oic...']),
 (0, 6, 'customer', ['by']),
 (0, 6, 'customer', ['bye'])]

Need to convert to

a=[(0,0,'customer',["Hi, I'm user"]),
 (0,1,'agent',['Hi Welcome']),
 (0, 2,'customer',["i would like to know"]),
 (0, 3, 'agent', ['Yes','Only credit']),
 (0, 4, 'customer', ['oic...','sub line?','is it?']),
 (0, 5, 'agent', ['no subline']),
 (0, 6, 'customer', ['oic...','by','bye'])]
```

I want to merge the list of responses based on the speaker (agent/customer). cant find quick logic... any help here?

Comment: What do you mean merge it? Tuples are immutable so theres no way to merge it. You can create a new list that looks like the second part of your post. Is that what you want?

Comment: You can use `itertools.groupby` to group elements. Something like `groupby(sorted(a, key=key_func), key=key_func)` where `key_func` can be something like `key_func = lambda i: i[1]`. Then you can merge the groups however you like

Comment: yes. @AzyCrw4282. same as the output

Comment: I suggest thinking about how you would do this by hand. First, you will iterate over each tuple in the list. But then what do you do when you look at a single record? How do you decide if it needs to be merged or not. As you think about these steps, write them down **in words**. Don't worry about Python syntax. Just describe the steps you need to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change it in_place as it's a tuple, so make another copy and check for pre-existing values to append to the list.

```
a=[(0,0,'customer',["Hi, I'm user"]),
 (0,1,'agent',['Hi Welcome']),
 (0,2,'customer',["i would like to know"]),
 (0, 3, 'agent', ['Yes']),
 (0, 3, 'agent', ['Only credit']),
 (0, 4, 'customer', ['oic...']),
 (0, 4, 'customer', ['sub line?']),
 (0, 4, 'customer', ['is it?']),
 (0, 5, 'agent', ['no subline']),
 (0, 6, 'customer', ['oic...']),
 (0, 6, 'customer', ['by']),
 (0, 6, 'customer', ['bye'])]

b = []
str2idx = []
idx = 0
for p in a:
  if p[:3] in str2idx:
    b[str2idx.index(p[:3])][3].append(p[3][0])
  else:
    b.append(p)
    str2idx.append(p[:3])
    idx += 1

print(b)
```